# Redis master is getting wrong ip, port of slave in kubernetes redis-sentinel

Tags: kubernetes, redis, dock, sentinel

While creating redis pods in kubernetes, redis-slave are able to connect to the master using the address mentioned, but in the redis-master the address of slave is wrong, it is always a address 10.44.0.0, due to which sentinel is not able to do the failover. Is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Redis Replica is announcing its internal pod network IP which is not reachable by other pods, such as master pods. You need to configure these two parameters in `redis.conf` using "reachable" ips.

```
sentinel announce-ip <ip>
sentinel announce-port <port>
```

As you are inside kubernetes you do not know in advance which ip/port will your replica use, so you can use `status.podIP` variable and pass it using an environment variable. You can see an example [here on k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables)

This can be a draft for your problem

```yaml
  containers:
  - name: redis
    image: redis
    env:
    - name: REPLICA_ANNOUNCE_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.podIP
    command:
    - redis-server
    args:
    - --replica-announce-ip $(REPLICA_ANNOUNCE_IP)
```

There are other options such us exposing the replicas behing a fixed ip clusterIP service. But IMHO this is simpler.

More info here
[Redis sentinel documentation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/sentinel)

Comment: This doesnt work, i have tried that already, the master is even able to replicate the data to the slave(connection is intact between the master and slave), imo when slave sends any data it goes through kubernetes interface and from there the master is picking-up the wrong address of slave. So what it boils down is that any packet going to the pods should have its external ip. ( Lets say a packet have been sent from google.com then the pod should receive address of google.com not the kubernetes internal address)